# Proving $f(x)=(1/2)(x+(1/x))$ is not one to one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let f : (0,∞)  → R be defined by $f(x):=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac1x))$. Prove that $f$ is not one to one (injective).

I understand the usual procedure for this would be to assume that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ and find a contradiction, but with all my algebraic powers I cannot find a way to prove this. Does anyone have any suggested starting points for me?

I've ended up with $xy(x-y)=y-x$ at one point, but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction. I also assume that I can cancel the $1/2$ constants out, is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x) = 2$ has [two solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%281%2F2%29+%28x+%2B+1%2Fx%29+%3D+2), so $f$ is not injective. To get the solutions explicitly, write

$$x + \frac{1}{x} = 4$$

and multiply by $x$ to get a quadratic.

Comment: This, or the generalization of setting $x+\frac1x=2c$, getting $x^2-2cx+1=0$, solving to get $$x=c\pm\sqrt{c^2-1}\;,$$ and observing that there are distinct solutions in the domain of $f$ whenever $c>1$, is probably the most straightforward approach; +1.

Answer (score 14):

Note that

$$f(x)=\frac12\left(x+\frac1x\right)$$

is completely symmetric with respect to $x$ and $\frac1x$:

$$f\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac12\left(\frac1x+\frac1{1/x}\right)=\frac12\left(\frac1x+x\right)=\ldots\;?$$

Comment: Smooth. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Did you arrive at this intuitively by just looking at the problem or is there some kind of process I can deduce this by?

Comment: Does anyone else hear jazz playing? I thought mine was clever...

Comment: @Christiaan: I know without really thinking about it that taking a reciprocal twice gives you the original number, so it was just a matter of looking at the problem and seeing that it treated $x$ and $\frac1x$ identically.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Continuity then gives the result.

Comment: This might be the most humorous use I've seen of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: How does continuity relate to a function being injective? I have a similar problem where I feel this might be useful.

Comment: @ChristiaanSwanepoel: Here's what continuity does for us here. The idea here is to pick any $0<x_0<\infty$. Since $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to0^+$, then every value greater than $f(x_0)$ is attained by $f$ somewhere to the left of $x_0$. Since $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty,$ then every value greater than $f(x_0)$ is attained by $f$ somewhere to the right of $x_0.$ And we're done.

Comment: For any $x>0$ note that $f((0,x))$ and $f((x,\infty))$ are intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$ or $[a,\infty)$. Any two intervals of this form have (a lot of) nontrivial intersection.

Comment: If I have f(x)→-∞ as x→0+ and f(x)→∞ as x→∞ for f:(0,∞)→R, does that imply that f(x) is injective?

Comment: @Christiaan: No: let $f(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(x+\frac{\pi}2\right)$ if $0<x<\frac{3\pi}4$, $f(x)=1$ if $\frac{3\pi}4\le x<4$, and $f(x)=x-3$ if $4\le x$, for instance.